# What is "someone" called when he or she "is involved in" something?

Tags: grammaticality, semantics

I'm looking for a word that describes a person by the activity he or she does. In Dutch we have a 'way' for a noun to be used as a description of action practitioner (eg: "betrokkene" vanuit "betrokken zijn"). 
In the same way as "some who uses something" is called a "user" and "someone who makes something" is called a "maker" or "creator".

Would "involve**r**" be an actually existing word for this case or is there something better?

In more specific details: I need a semantics word for "someone that is involved in/by" (against its will/knowledge) an incident/accident. This word should describe both victims and witnesses of the incident/accident without labeling them as either victim or witness. This last is because there might be more ways to be involved in an accident/incident than simply being a victim or witness (eg: your car might be used without you driving it -> you are neither witness or victim but you might get involved in the police questioning -> you are one of "those involved" -> an "involver"?)

Many of the dictionaries do mention "in-vol-ver" as some sort of afterthought, but when you click that word it seems not an actual word that is known to the dictionary. Even a plain google search on "involver" doesn't turn up anything useful or remotely close to it in my case. (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/involver the article looks almost computer generated)

Comment: Some who is involved in something is a participant. You seem to want: an unwilling participant....

Comment: 'Persons involved' or 'persons concerned' in the accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a ***BYSTANDER***:

: one who is present but not taking part in a situation or event

: a chance spectator

// innocent 
bystanders who were injured in the shooting

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bystander)

Answer (score 0):

In a vague sense you are a "**party**" in the activity (incident)... or "**party to**" the activity (as an idiom?). Your exact involvement can be further defined when/if necessary. It is another way of saying all those involved.

> How each person (**party**) was involved was not certain, but all
>   **parties** were gathered together in one place...

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/party+to

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/parties

https://www.freethesaurus.com/parties

Comment: ah yes, I see. Does this also apply to the execution of the action by the person -> "partaking in" as in being involved in the incident/accident (the "involver" part)?